# How to list all storage (internal and external) and absolute path in Android?

Tags: android

My minSdkVersion is 16, I hope to get all storage (include internal and external) and absolute path.

The absolute path maybe like /storage/sdcard0/, how can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the kernel exported file `/proc/mounts` to get the entire list of mounted file system on your device. The seconds column from `/proc/mounts` is the mounted point.

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/proc/mounts")));
    List<String> mountPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    String l;
    while ((l = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String p = l.split("\\s+")[1];
        if (p != null && p.startsWith(File.separator)) {
            mountPoints.add(p);
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "all mount absolute points " + Arrays.toString(mountPoints.toArray()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I get the result [/, /dev, /dev/pts, /dev/cpuctl, /dev/usb-ffs/adb, /proc, /sys, /sys/fs/selinux, /sys/kernel/debug, /sys/fs/cgroup, /acct, /mnt/secure, /mnt/asec, /mnt/obb, /firmware-modem, /firmware, /system, /data, /cache, /persist, /efs, /persdata/absolute, /mnt/shell/emulated, /mnt/shell/knox-emulated, /storage/emulated, /mnt/media_rw/extSdCard, /storage/extSdCard, /storage/emulated/0, /storage/emulated/legacy]